# How to display html formatted text in unity new ui Text?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

How could i display html formatted text to unity's new ui Text?

Ex.

```
<p>This is some <b><font size="3" color="red">Text</b></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this

```
This is some <b><size=50><color=#ff0000ff>Text</color></size></b>
```

Comment: it was just simple example. The main issue i am facing is i want to support html tags and would love to know if there is any way with unity ui to achieve it (as nGUI has html support) or is there any workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Unity documentation the only supported tags in Rich Text foramt are as follows :

```
<b> <i> <size> <color>
```

Now as a workaround to get more advanced html tags working in unity you might want to try a Html texture like the one provided [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/HtmlTexturePlugin). The idea that comes to mind is that you write your html formatted text as a normal .html file and the have it render to a texture and use that texture in your game. Might work dont know. :D

Comment: Yes, Unity Rich Text has very very limited support as of now. HtmlTexturePlugin, i didn't found any example of using it for html formatted text (its for rendering whole http site within unity3d, but thats not i needed). What i want is similar to this https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/7918

Answer (score 0):

Try TMText Rich Text.

You can do more styles, including colors:

```
<color="red">Red <color=#005500>Dark Green <#0000FF>Blue <color=#FF000088>Semitransparent Red
```

Learn more here:
http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/